# Stack numpy array onto diagonal

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Given N 2d numpy arrays, is there a neat way in which I can 'stack' or 'bolt' them together on the diagonal, filling any new slots with 0? E.g. given:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4]])

arr2 = np.array([[9, 8, 7],
                 [6, 5, 4],
                 [3, 2, 1]])
```

I want to create:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                [3, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                [0, 0, 9, 8, 7],
                [0, 0, 6, 5, 4],
                [0, 0, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There's a function for that.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html)

```
scipy.linalg.block_diag(arr1, arr2)
```

It takes arbitrarily many parameters:

```
scipy.linalg.block_diag(*list_of_arrays)
```

Comment: Haha I just found that too! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros((5, 5))
>>> arr[:2, :2] = arr1
>>> arr[2:, 2:] = arr2
```

And, to verify that it worked, we can display `arr`:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  9.,  8.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  6.,  5.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: This is the strategy that `block_diag` uses.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this which seems to do exactly what I need:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html

```
>> from scipy.linalg import block_diag
>>> A = [[1, 0],
...      [0, 1]]
>>> B = [[3, 4, 5],
...      [6, 7, 8]]
>>> C = [[7]]
>>> block_diag(A, B, C)
[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 3 4 5 0]
 [0 0 6 7 8 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np` has a relatively new `block` function that concatenates nested lists of arrays.  But it requires specifying the zero fill blocks:

```
In [15]: np.block([[arr1, np.zeros((2,3),int)], [np.zeros((3,2),int), arr2]])
Out[15]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 9, 8, 7],
       [0, 0, 6, 5, 4],
       [0, 0, 3, 2, 1]])
```